# How to fill in rows in a grouped dataframe? (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

For example, if I have a dataframe grouped by 3 categories:

```
x = data.frame(
  location = c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  type=c('a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'),
  time=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4),value=c(12,56,57,58,24,35,57,86,46,35)
)


   location type time value
1         1    a    1    12
2         2    b    1    56
3         2    b    2    57
4         2    b    3    58
5         2    b    4    24
6         2    b    5    35
7         3    c    1    57
8         3    c    2    86
9         3    c    3    46
10        3    c    4    35
```

I want to have output that contains every location with every type at every time interval. (The three groupings would be filled in but the value would be empty)

Any ideas? Pandas seems to have stack and unstack but I'm not sure how this is mimicked in R.

EDIT: The desired output here should look something like this

```
   location type time value
1         1    a    1    12
2         1    a    2    0
3         1    a    3    0
4         1    a    4    0
5         1    a    5    0
6         1    b    1    0
7         1    b    2    0
8         1    b    3    0
9         1    b    4    0
10        1    b    5    0
```

..... and so on

Comment: Can you add the expected output ?

Comment: I think tidyr::expand probably does this if you're in that 'verse, maybe followed with a left_join, like `expand(x, location, type, time) %>% left_join(x)`

Comment: @ManishSaraswat yes I have just added the expected output. and thank you Frank for the edited code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid()` and adding @markus and @Frank's suggestions:

```
y <- expand.grid(sapply(x[, 1:3], unique))
xy <- merge(y, x, all=TRUE)
str(xy)
# 'data.frame':   45 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ location: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ type    : Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ time    : num  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
#  $ value   : num  12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
head(xy)
#   location type time value
# 1        1    a    1    12
# 2        1    a    2    NA
# 3        1    a    3    NA
# 4        1    a    4    NA
# 5        1    a    5    NA
# 6        1    b    1    NA
```

Comment: Just saw that my solution is almost the same as yours. You could write `y <- expand.grid(sapply(x[, 1:3], unique))` and save some lines.

Comment: This is very close - is there a way to keep the values intact? For instance, location 1, type a, time 1 should have a value of 12 from the previous dataframe before expanding whereas you have a column of all 0's. Is the easiest way to remedy this just to left join?

Comment: @N.Kim `merge(y,x,all=TRUE)` instead of the `y <- data.frame(...)` step, maybe.